# I am trying to return a nonzero exit code on an Xcode Run Script build phase, but it's not working

Tags: ios, xcode, exit-code

I have a script in my build phase that I am trying to 'return exit 1' after I throw a build error.

This is coming from a command line tool that is logging 'return exit 1' after there is a problem. The exit 1 shows up on the log, but Xcode still is telling me I need to return a nonzero exit code...

[image]

Any ideas?
EDIT

Here is the type of script:

[image]

Comment: What language is the script in? Why not just `exit 1;`?

Comment: Can you add to your question the snippet of code that you do the "return exit 1"?

Comment: It's a Command Line Utility, and it is literally printf("return exit 1;");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is presumably a (bash) shell script. In that case you shouldn't be using `return exit 1;` you should just be using `exit 1`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the post with an image from Xcode. Does this mean it is a shell script?

Comment: Yes, that means it's a shell script.

Comment: So I am printing out exit 1 to the console, shouldn't it be recognizing it?

Comment: No, printing isn't exiting. Why are you printing?

Comment: Or is it possible to check if there is any output from the Tool and then just exit 1 from within Xcode?

Comment: Don't print the exit text, run the exit command. Remove the print and just exit.

Comment: @Casper If your "script" is a C program, you don't need to call `exit(1)`. You can call `return 1` in `main`. It is the return value of `main` that gives the result code. Of course `exit(1)` will work but calling `exit` inside `main` is silly.